# Problem in conditional steps that causes id duplication in workflow

Tags: github-actions

In one of my steps, I need to set a value based on some condition, and if the condition is not met, set another value. For example:

```
      - name: Some name
        id: some-id
        if: $SOME_CONDITION
        run: |
          echo "name=hello" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

        - name: Another name
        id: some-id
        if: !$SOME_CONDITION
        run: |
          echo "name=bye" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I need this because when I want to use this output I'm able to access it through `${{ steps.some-id.outputs.name }}`
But this is not possible due to id duplication. What solutions exist to solve this problem?

Comment: Put the condition inside a single step? Without context and constraints it's hard to know.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What context is needed? I want to access to the first commit of the current PR, in case of a pull request event, this commit is the most recent common commit between current branch and base branch, in case of push (after the PR is merged) I want this to be the first commit of the repo

Comment: Most obviously: _what_ condition? From what you've posted something like `echo 'name=${{ SOME_CONDITION && 'hello' || 'bye' }}' >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"` would probably work.

Answer (score 0):

In GitHub Actions workflows, you cannot reuse an id within the jon. Each step within a job needs a unique id for identification.

Instead of trying to use the same id for two different steps, you can consolidate the conditional logic within a single step and set the output accordingly. Here's how you can do it:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Some name
    id: some-id
    run: |
      if ${{ SOME_CONDITION }}; then
        echo "name=hello" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      else
        echo "name=bye" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      fi
```

To use the name variable from this step, do the below:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Use conditional output
    run: echo "The conditional output is ${{ steps.some-id.outputs.name }}"
```